# What is stored in laravel’s default cookies/sessions?

Tags: laravel, cookies

Per default laravel creates 2 cookies: XSRF-TOKEN and my_app_session.

I’ve `base64_decode`d it and there is an array with the keys `iv`, `value` and `mac` in it.

Is there any personal data stored in those cookies?
Is it conform with GDPR?

Answer (score 2):

The cookies of Laravel do comply with GDPR, as no personal information is stored.

**XSRF-TOKEN**

That information is used to protect your site against [Cross Site Request Forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). A purely technical protection mechanism.

**my_app_session**

This hold information about the current session of the logged in user of your application. It is necessary to track it for again, purely technical reasons.

I can assure you that no personal information, that could be not compliant with GDPR are stored.

Storing data of users, might it be personal or not, is allowed if you can explain a legitimate interest in storing these. This is also explained in detail on the [GDPR site](https://www.gdpreu.org/the-regulation/key-concepts/legitimate-interest/)

As these two tokens are created even in cmopletely new Laravel applications where no user data is present/stored, you can answer the question yourself, if any GDPR non-compliant data is stored ;-)

Comment: thx for your answer. What makes me doubt is the fact, that an IP- or MAC-address is also a personal data. And there is this key `mac`, which could be the mac-address!?